# How to add icons to iTerm2?

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm, color, themes

I've been looking into making my terminal more visually expressive. So far I've found , and learnt how to import themes and customize color schemes, but I was wondering how people get these cool icons and visual modifications as seen in these images. Can anyone provide me with some useful links?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first prompt you show a picture of looks like a customized version of [a powerline oh-my-zsh theme](https://github.com/jeremyFreeAgent/oh-my-zsh-powerline-theme). It requires [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh). There is also a [version that supports bash, zsh, and fish](https://github.com/milkbikis/powerline-shell).

To use those, you need a [Powerline-patched font](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts).

Your second screenshot comes from [dracula-theme](https://github.com/zenorocha/dracula-theme), a color scheme and prompt for lots of different editors plus oh-my-zsh.

Personally, I would not recommend oh-my-zsh, as in my experience it was kind of slow and heavy. I created my own bash prompt using Powerline symbols, but milkbikis/powerline-shell is probably the best one to use.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

oh-my-zsh is an open source, community-driven framework for managing your Zsh configuration.

It comes bundled with a ton of helpful functions, helpers, plugins, themes, and a few things that make you shout…

[Github Project](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh)

[image]

[Themes](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes)

Comment: Does that shell include the nice VCS branch arrow ui shown in my second screenshot?

Comment: Yes I think so.

Comment: nice copy pasting the readme from zsh's githug page, great job

Answer (score 0):

Consider installing Powerlevel9k, a popular and highly customizable terminal theme for the shell Zsh.

I used this blog post to get started:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-you-can-style-your-terminal-like-medium-freecodecamp-or-any-way-you-want-f499234d48bc

Once you have everything installed, you may want to visit this git repo to see plenty of customization examples: https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k/wiki/Show-Off-Your-Config

[image: Powerlevel9k customozation example]